# Will the aptitude/multiarch bug allow a successful upgrade from 10.04 LTS to 12.04LTS on a 64bit workstation?

Tags: 10.04, 12.04, multiarch, release-upgrade

The release notes say in known issues "Aptitude does not work on 64-bit systems without disabling multiarch in /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch . ([831768](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768))"

Is this going to fail my i386 stuff in my amd64 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS release upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because we don't use `aptitude` to upgrade between releases. We use `update-manager` for that (it uses APT under the hood, but not `aptitude`).

Comment: So even even though the i386 stuff will upgrade ok, does multiarch handle dependencies now for i386 stuff seamlessly?

Comment: It's not entirely seamless. Libraries need to be converted to multi-arch, and packages that are going to be widely cross-installed may need some tweaking. Oh, and aptitude has better multiarch support, but it's not great yet.

Comment: I upgraded my x86 system to 12.04 Gnome Classic with out problems, but my amd64 upgrade was a disaster with many things broken including a stalled multiarch update and dependency problems in installing gnome-session.

Comment: Didea you have many PPAs? If it was a fairly clean system, please file a bug.

Comment: This 64bit is Otto's (the Orkin  man) little piece of heaven.  Bug reports are being filed, yet multiach doesn't seem to be a source.  The only one I got there was a lib used by google picasa/earth.  I am now just tying to get 10.10>11.04 to work.

Comment: The end result, once all the other bugs have been sorted out (but not fixed) only the one insignificant error related to multiarch was found.  Have made it all the way to 12.04, now waiting (and hoping) the other major bugs will be fixed.